# Download Office before or after connecting computer to server?

Tags: networking, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

I work at a small business with very limited access to IT support, so I apologize for having a "Servers for Dummies" question. I am trying to get several new computers as ready as possible to save time/money when our IT contractor arrives later this week to connect them to the server. With the new computers, we will also be switching to Office 365 Business Premium subscriptions, and I don't want to waste his time downloading the Office apps onto the desktops if he doesn't have to do that. Is it okay for me to download the apps onto the computers now, or will the apps only work after the computer has been connected to the server? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what does `server` exactly mean? Or at least, what type of service does it provide?

Comment: What Alex said.  Will the contractor be adding the new computers to AD, or will he be "connecting them to the server" some other way?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for you to save time on installing Office 365 ProPlus on company computers: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg998766.aspx

The prefered way is to have the latest Office files downloaded into a shared folder which you can use to install on company computers: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219424.aspx

And of course, if you're using Images to create new computers, you can install Office as part of the image file: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314789.aspx